Make an Alias of EZA command
This is my $PROFILE config
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\agnoster.omp.json | Invoke-Expression

New-Alias -Name "nano" -Value "c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\nano.exe"

New-Alias -Name "grep" -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe"

New-Alias -Name "ll" -Value "eza.exe -a -l --color=always --icons"

everything works fine except for "ll" which gives me this error

ll : The term 'eza.exe -a -l --color=always --icons' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.

but eza itself works: eza.exe -a -l --color=always --icons
I've installed eza by winget and this is my version:

eza - A modern, maintained replacement for ls v0.20.5 [+git]
https://github.com/eza-community/eza

Others info:

winget list | findstr "eza" eza
eza-community.eza                         0.20.5
winget

On where eza no result come back.
I found the pkg installed on:

C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\eza-community.eza_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe

This directory is on my PATH

 salva@Glamdring    ERROR  $env:Path | grep "WinGet" C:\Program
Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma
SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program
Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
Files\Calibre2;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program
Files\gs\gs10.04.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA app\NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Rust
stable GNU 1.81\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance
Toolkit;C:\mingw64\bin;C:\pngquant;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin;C:\Users\salva\scoop\shims;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\eza-community.eza_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe;C:\Program
Files
(x86)\WindowsGrep;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\sharkdp.fd_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\fd-v10.2.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\junegunn.fzf_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe;C:\Program
Files (x86)\Midnight
Commander;C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\eza-community.eza_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe;

Any idea how to fix it?

Did you consider giving it a fully qualified path, just like you did the other three? It seems like the obvious solution.

@KenWhite yes, it was also complicated to find the location of eza but I did and nothing changed

It's not complicated to locate if you can run it from the command line. Use where eza.exe. If it doesn't work from the command line, then you've identified the problem - it's not on the system PATH. If you've tried the fully qualified path and it didn't work, then you've not entered it correctly, because using a full path always works. (Also, Windows Explorer has search functionality, so you can find any file that's on your computer.)

@KenWhite I updated the question with others informations

Is there an eza.exe in the folder you've listed? If not, then you've not found the right directory or you don't have a Win32/Win64 executable, which cannot be executed directly.

new-alias only accepts single command, no arguments.  you can create a function like function run-myezacommand{eza.exe -a -l --color=always --icons} and then do new-alias -name ll -value run-myezacommand, though I guess you might as well just name the function ll and then no need for alias...

@Daniel can you make this an answer to the question so I can mark it as a solution?

@Filburt ok, ty but who knew this was the problem?
